# Small overdose in current -- dangerous?

Tags: current, cellphone, damage

(I have a feeling that this question may be off-topic here because it is so utterly, enormously basic, and hardly related to engineering at all. Please bear with me...)

My phone came with a power cable that outputs 1 ampere. I have a different cable that outputs 2.1 ampere, which can be plugged in in a car's cigarette lighter socket. Is there a chance of damaging the phone in case I use the second cable? If not, why is this? Is it because an "overdose" in current simply does no harm, or because the difference is too small?

Comment: Is it off-topic? Absolutely not. Has it already been asked? Yes.

Comment: If Johny wants to eat 2 apples, he will eat only 2, whether you provide 2.5,3 or 4, it doesn't matter to Johny - Olin Lathrop.